# DB open fails error in Android and could be due to the DB file location

Tags: android, database

I created DB table from DB Brower for SQLite and save to the below path but getting error when I clicked the button to read db file. Not sure whether it is due to file location or my code.

[image]

But when I try to open the DB from the code it gives me below errors

2020-04-04 10:19:51.975 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
2020-04-0

```
4 10:19:51.982 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme E/SQLiteAssetHelper: Couldn't open OrderForMeDB for writing (will try read-only):
    com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/OrderForMeDB file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:347)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:321)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:254)
        at com.dav2020.orderforme.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:50)
        at com.dav2020.orderforme.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
2020-04-04 10:19:51.982 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 32460 of [69906880ce]
2020-04-04 10:19:51.982 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:32460: (2) open(/data/user/0/com.dav2020.orderforme/databases/OrderForMeDB) - 
2020-04-04 10:19:51.983 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.dav2020.orderforme/databases/OrderForMeDB'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
        at com.dav2020.orderforme.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:50)
        at com.dav2020.orderforme.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
2020-04-04 10:19:51.983 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-04-04 10:19:51.983 6995-6995/com.dav2020.orderforme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dav2020.orderforme, PID: 6995
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
        at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
        at com.dav2020.orderforme.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:50)
        at com.dav2020.orderforme.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

This is the code where I use DB

```
public void addToCart(Order order)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount) " +
                "VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                order.getProductId(),
                order.getProductName(),
                order.getQuantity(),
                order.getPrice(),
                order.getDiscount()
        );
        db.execSQL(query);
    }


public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView food_name, food_price, food_description;
    ImageView food_image;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    FloatingActionButton btnCart;
    ElegantNumberButton numberButton;

    String foodId="";

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference food;
    Food currentFood;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

        //Init Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        food = database.getReference("food");

        //init view
        numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        btnCart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

        btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                        foodId,
                        currentFood.getName(),
                        numberButton.getNumber(),
                        currentFood.getPrice(),
                        currentFood.getDiscount()
                ));
                Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this,"Added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_description);
        food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        food_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_food);

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppbar);

        //get food ID from foodlist
        if(getIntent() != null)
            foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
        if(!foodId.isEmpty()){
            getDetailedFood(foodId);
        }
    }



       private void getDetailedFood(String foodId) {
            food.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    currentFood = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
                    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(currentFood.getImage())
                            .into(food_image);
                    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(currentFood.getName());
                    food_price.setText(currentFood.getPrice());
                    food_name.setText(currentFood.getName());
                    food_description.setText(currentFood.getDescription());



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried to move DB file under my Java folder but app still crashes with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you put DB file in wrong place Put your DB file and place in Java folder [image]

Comment: I have tried to move the assets folder under Java and under my project folder but both are not working..

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... the location was correct. assets folder must be located under main. 
The issue was my DB name. I set as below and realized that I forgot to add extension .db
private static final String DB_NAME="OrderForMeDB";

after I change to below it works. 
private static final String DB_NAME="OrderForMeDB.db";